# Data binding in asp.net : listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, data-binding, webforms

I'm new to web development using .net and am having issues in binding data from business logic to a table. I'm basically trying to populate a table dynamically.

**Table in a list view i want to populate**

```
<asp:ListView ID="processList" runat="server" 
            DataKeyNames="procName" GroupItemCount="1"
            ItemType="SerMon.RemoteProcess" SelectMethod="fetchFromQueue">
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table >
                    <tr>
                        <td>No data was returned.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <EmptyItemTemplate>
                <td/>
            </EmptyItemTemplate>
            <GroupTemplate>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                    <td id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></td>
                </tr>
            </GroupTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <td runat="server">
                    <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-hover ">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Process</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Machine</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblId"><%#: Item.ProcName%></asp:Label></td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1"><%#: Item.Procstatus%></asp:Label></td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2"><%#: Item.mcName%></asp:Label></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    </p>
                </td>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:ListView>
```

**Method which is called to populate table**

```
public List<RemoteProcess> fetchFromQueue()
    {
        List<RemoteProcess> pl = new List<RemoteProcess>();
        foreach (CloudQueueMessage message in queue.GetMessages(5, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)))
        {
            Debug.Write(message.AsString);
            RemoteProcess m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RemoteProcess>(message.AsString);
            pl.Add(m);
            //queue.DeleteMessage(message);
        }
        return pl;
    }
```

The table is generated but theres no data. Also for some odd reason, five tables are generated( This is always equal to the number specified in the getMessage function)

Comment: I think in your case it would be better to use a `GridView` Control instead of the `ListView` Control.

Comment: Try removing `GroupItemCount="1"` to avoid 5 tables.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Nope, tried it. Does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if GroupTemplate is required for you in the ListView. The reason you were getting multiple table was that you have defined table header and row both in the item template. The ItemTemplate should have only structure of the item display. The LayoutTemplate should have the structure of the over all layout of how data should look like.

I have changed the ListView as following it make it look like a proper table.

```
<asp:ListView ID="processList" runat="server"
    DataKeyNames="procName" 
    ItemType="WebApplication1.Models.RemoteProcess" SelectMethod="fetchFromQueue">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>No data was returned.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <EmptyItemTemplate>
        <td />
    </EmptyItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server" id="table1">
            <thead>
                <tr runat="server">
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Process</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Machine</th>
                </tr>
                 <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr runat="server">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblId"><%#: Item.procName%></asp:Label></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1"><%#: Item.Procstatus%></asp:Label></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2"><%#: Item.mcName%></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Please note here that I have removed the GroupTemplate and setting related to it as I wasn't sure how to group the data.

This should help resolving your issue.

Comment: That worked ! Not getting multiple tables but the data is still not being populated. procName and Machine columns are empty but status column is always 0. I have double checked the object being passed and it contains the required data, its just not being displayed.

Comment: Check if you are getting the data from the source? Put a breakpoint on `return pl` and debug the code. See what values are being populated in `pl`.